# Mounting drives in lubuntu from remote desktop session

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, lubuntu, fstab

I am using a remote desktop client to connect a lubuntu server and I am having a problem mounting some drives. I have setup a bunch of auto mount hard drives. Those drives mount fine when I login to the server directly. However, when I remote in and try to mount the drives I get "Messeage recipient disconnected from message bus without replying (g-dbus-error-quark,4).

For auto mount options I used: nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show.

Comment: Try using defaults instead of the options you used for mount.

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you said it didnt work but after hours of investigations I found the problem. Somehow while I was playing with different configuration options for mount Disks GUI replicated entries on /etc/fstab. Once I removed duplicates it works.